# SQL Return unique values from duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it even posible to have SQL statment to the return the unique values from fields2-8 from all records that have duplicates in field1(multiple different values duplicated)? i truely have tried to read/search/write and test but i cant even come close. If i posted what i have it would just be junk.Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
ID      Field1      Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5      Field6  Field7  Field8
167128  DOCC1728544 1500174 Rlse    411þ615 1/1/1940    Roland  Mary    4.6A
167141  DOCC1728544 1500174 Rlse    411þ615 1/1/1940    Hubert  Mary    4.6A
178272  DOCC1728544 1500174 Rlse    411þ615 1/1/1940    Leola   Mary    4.6A
139260  DOCC1728544 1500174 Rlse    411þ615 1/1/1940    Lottie  Mary    4.6A
139261  DOCC1728544 1500174 Rlse    411þ615 1/1/1940    Walter  Mary    4.6A
200243  DOCC1728544 1500174 Deed    411þ615 1/1/1940    Nan     Atlas   256 1
```

My Table (name: [New(T)]) contains multiple blocks like this and i need it to return values like this

```
DOCC1728544 1500174 Rlse,Deed   411þ615 1/1/1940    Roland,Hubert,Leola,Lottie,Walter,Nan   Mary,Atlas  4.6A,256 1
```

Again thanks for any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: it is possible, in mysql it called group_concat

Comment: i am using access sql queries

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, it would look something like this

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT field3) as field3, field4, field5,
GROUP_CONCAT(field6) as field6, field7, field8
FROM table
WHERE field1 = 'DOCC1728544'
LIMIT 1;
```

It looks like you want to group multiple values from the same column together. To do that we use `GROUP CONCAT(distinct col)`. In this case, we are performing a group concatenation on both field3 and field6.

We're looking for only one record, so we simply use the `LIMIT 1` statement.

Here's the fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89a7af/3/0

If you are using POSTGRES, you can use a combination of `array_to_string` and `array_agg`.

```
SELECT id, field1, field2, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field3), ',') as field3,
field4, field5, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT field6), ',') as field6, field7, field8
FROM table
WHERE field1 = 'DOCC1728544'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much i am reading up and try to apply this. there are multiple different duplicates in field1 not shown in my exsample.

Comment: In Postgres, `string_agg()` would be the better choice

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how would I do that. Just do `string_agg(DISTINCT field3)`?